# Codeblocks outputs broken executable

Tags: c++

I have downloaded plenty of different versions of code blocks, and none of them compiles quite right. My hello world runs within code blocks just fine. However, when I run the executable outside of codeblocks, it says "Hello.exe has stopped working". There isn't anything wrong with my code (I don't think.) and my mingw compiles fine outside of codeblocks. What does codeblocks do to my executable? Is there some option to fix this? I am on windows 7 64 bit, and my current code blocks version is 10.05. My program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've been using it for quite a while on Windows 7 64-bit. It's never done that for me.

Comment: @chris Hmm. Its never not done that to me. I'm sad

Comment: I have seen this error before. However, it fixed itself like magic and didn't leave me any time to figure out what was wrong. I guess it was because of the project properties that Code::Block set. You might wanna check that. Some variable paths can be wrong.

Comment: @remyabel Not really the same problem.....

Comment: it links against the gnu libs. If their not in your system path, you'll get that error.

Comment: @johnathon you mean i should add my mingw to my environmental variables?

Comment: try somewhere the windows loader can find them. system32 , or the same folder as the executable.

Comment: or, run regsvr32 on them. which you'll have to do anyways after ya stick em in system32

Comment: @johnathon I fixed it all! I got a different version of mingw!

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem. I had a broken compiler (or something like that). My suggestion for other people with this problem is to experiment with different versions of the minGW compiler. Also, change the version of code blocks you are using, or even uninstall everything and restart. The problem with mine was I downloaded a bad compiler. [The truth is, codeblocks isn't the best ide.]

Comment: Can you outline your steps so other people with the same issue can find a solution?

Comment: @remyabel It really isn't in steps. I did something totally wrong. It was a pretty stupidd question int the first place